# Blender steps in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I'd like to do array modifier equivalent in geometry nodes. Image below to clarify it more [image]

Comment: [This Tutorial](https://youtu.be/8PkdI87qDho) will give you a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another simple setup is to delete part of a cube and instance it along a line like so:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank You for answer works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

A more mathematical approach, which won't require you to use weld modifier:

[image]

Added solidify for thickness:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

a very basic stair setup is this:

[image]

result:

[image]